# How to continue downloading the file Java (socket)

Tags: java, sockets

I'm doing a program that sends large files through sockets client-server, that piece of code

```
while ((bytesRead = in.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length)) != -1) {
     bos.write(mybytearray, 0, bytesRead);
}
```

[All code can be found here](https://github.com/Vlad161/MiniProj/blob/master/src/Client.java)

I have already downloaded data as where to pass this number was spooled file? For example there is a file size 35000 bytes transmitted 20000 is broken and how to make the program to start downloading from 20000 bytes to continue?
P.S. I`m very sorry, my English is bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you open the connection to the destination file just keep reading it until you reach 20000 bytes, discarding the data.

After you reach your "resume point" start appending the new data to the existing file.

Unfortunately you cannot "seek" a socket the same way you would in something like local file I/O.